# How to make Flutter RaisedButton selected state

Tags: flutter

How to make `RaisedButton` as selected state as in toggle button selected state?

How to make `RaisedButton` not taking extra width, i.e, shrimpWrap the label text.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe I have managed to do the same thing without using `RaisedButton`.

From my understanding you are trying to make `RaisedButton` switch between two cases in your first question, you can achieve this by alternating between the two `States` when `onPressed` is called.

However, in order to answer your second question as well, I used a `Container` instead of a `RaisedButton` , this `Container` acts now as a `Button` and when tapped, it switches between states. And the `Container` will be sizing itself to its `child`, which is the `Text` that has a changing state in my example (The `String` and `Color` values).

Finally, in order to give this `Container` a similar behavior to the press functionality of the `RaisedButton`, I wrapped it within a `GestureDetector`, and controlled the change of the state inside `onTap` call.

Here is my full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Color _myColor = Colors.green;
  String _myAccountState = "Account Enabled";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Manage Accounts"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new Center(
          child: new GestureDetector(
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
              child: new Text(
                _myAccountState, style: new TextStyle(color: _myColor),),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_myColor == Colors.green) {
                  _myAccountState = "Account Disabled";
                  _myColor = Colors.orange;
                }
                else {
                  _myAccountState = "Account Enabled";
                  _myColor = Colors.green;
                }
              });
            },

          )
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

PS: For a switch on/off behavior, you can definitely use `RaisedButton` and produce a similar behavior as follows:

```
return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Manage Accounts"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(_myAccountState),
            new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("Click Me"), color: _myColor, onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_myColor == Colors.green) {
                  _myAccountState = "Account Disabled";
                  _myColor = Colors.red;
                }
                else {
                  _myAccountState = "Account Enabled";
                  _myColor = Colors.green;
                }
              });
            })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

However, the only reason I tried using a `Container` with a `GestureDetector` is to answer your second question, I am not sure how to use shrinkWrap with a `RaisedButton`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reproduce a "2 state button" I personny use `AnimatedCrossFade` to switch between a `RaisedButton` and a `OutlineButton`. This way the state is handled directly in the `crossFadeState` property of `AnimatedCrossFade` widget.

Here is a widget you can use anywhere you want. The width is set to avoid bad clipping effect. It has to be sufficent to display the full text. As it's a stateless widget it's the responsability of the user of this widget to change the state.

```
class ToggleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final selected, onChange, textSelected, textUnselected, width;

  ToggleButton({this.textSelected, this.textUnselected, this.selected, this.onChange, this.width = 150}) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedCrossFade(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      crossFadeState: selected ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
      firstChild: Container(
        width: width,
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text(textSelected),
          onPressed: () {
            onChange(false);
          },
        ),
      ),
      secondChild: Container(
        width: width,
        child: OutlineButton(
          child: Text(textUnselected),
          onPressed: () {
            onChange(true);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you can use this widget as simply as :

```
ToggleButton(
  textSelected: "Account enabled",
  textUnselected: "Account disabled",
  width: 150,
  selected: _accountEnabled,
  onChange: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _accountEnabled = value;
    });
  },
)
```